# Why do I keep getting the permission denied error after giving Everyone full access to the file?

Tags: python, windows, pip, permissions

Firstly I wanted to edit the pip.ini file because I kept getting the **Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/yfinance/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/yfinance/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping** when using pip install [package name]

Than I found this: [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) where it suddgested that I open the pip.ini file and add this:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

And now I am having trouble editing the pip.ini file, after watching many tutorials and video explanation videos on how to solve the problem I keep getting the "YOU DO NOT HAVE THE PERMISSION TO EDIT THIS FILE". I have changed users permissions under properties->security tab and nothing is helping, I still cannot edit the file
[image]

[image]

The error translates to: You do not have the permission to open this file, to open it get the permission from an admin or from the owner.

**So to sum up I am trying to fix the SLLCertVerificationError but I can't fix it because I can't open the pip.ini file. Any ideas?**

**Note:** My I have downloaded python 3.10 from microsoft store and that is why the file location might be a bit odd.

Comment: Use the Python installation from https://python.org. The MS Store version can have lots of issues.

Comment: But how can I fix the permission error?

Comment: Don't use the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Could it be that this file has the read-only attribute set?

Comment: I haven't thought about that, I will check and let you know.

Comment: No the file doesn't have a read-only attribute set

Comment: @MattDMo I have installed the one from python.org and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED IT**

Firstly run the : pip config -v debug to see if pip.ini file exists.
Than create a pip.ini file in the given directory and add:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```